# Many to many SQL generation statements in Django 1.4

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-1.4

The django1.4 release notes say:

- The many to many SQL generation functions on the database backends will be removed.

Can somebody point me to these functions? Where are they located?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was removed in django 1.4, but you can see the code (and deprecation warning) in the [django 1.3 source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.3.X/django/db/backends/creation.py#L135).